# HTTPRequest class not recognised, doesnt appear to have an apache.jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache

I'm trying to compile the following code (to see if i can get a web serverto stream to a client):

```
           HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

           HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest("GET", "http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616.html");

           // returns immediately if the complete header (not message!) is received
           HttpResponse resp = httpClient.call(req);

           if (resp.getStatus() == 200) {  
              // create the output file 
              File file = new File("rfc2616.html");
              file.createNewFile();
              FileChannel fc = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();

              // get a blocking message body channel
              ReadableByteChannel inputBodyChannel = resp.getBlockingBody();

              // and transfer the data
              fc.transferFrom(inputBodyChannel, 0, 900000);
              fc.close();
           }
```

but eclipse doesn't recognise the HTTPRequest class and i dont have any apache jars which support it, even though i added all the apache .jars to my build path?

Answer (score 0):

That's the [HttpComponents Client 4.x API](http://hc.apache.org). You can download it [here](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi). Perhaps you had version 3.x instead which indeed lacks the `HttpRequest` class.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a late answer but I came across this problem myself.

### How I encountered the Problem

In Eclipse I used maven and the HttpRequest class by just binding the httpclient of **org.apache.httpcomponents** likes this:

for the dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

for copying by the maven compiler plugin as a package into the target/dependency folder:

```
<artifactItem>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>4.5</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <overWrite>true</overWrite>
</artifactItem>
```

After doing that I could easily use the HttpRequest class within the eclipse environment.

Nevertheless, after executing `mvn package` and starting the created jar of my application, I got a ClassNotFoundException for org.apache.http.HttpRequest.

### The Solution that worked for me

So if you ever come across this problem, make sure you include other jars that are required by the `httpclient` for proper functioning (**httpcore**, **commons-logging**, **commons-codec**):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
  <version>4.4.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
  <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Please refer to the [mvn repositories](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/) for the most recent versions.